# Where is constraintlayout part in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am started using constraint layout on Android but I couldn't find constrant's part. Where is it? Where should I place constraint? It's now showing when I selected a widget

[image]

Comment: what version of android studio is this?

Comment: paste your xml. There are errors that's why it's not showing you the Button. If button is visible you can see the constraints for it  when you select it

Comment: Androud studio 3.0 and also I drag item there to create constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the bottom your preview is not working ok because under Android Canary 3 previews using AppCompat support libraries version 26.0.0-beta2 brokes UI as reported in the following issue:

[bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62749978)

WORKAROUND: Temporarily rollback your support libraries version to 26.0.0-beta1 version and you will see the design view without errors.